# Symbol Level in ArcGIS 9: 'Broken' look of symbols, how to resolve

Tags: arcmap, cartography, symbology

I am using symbol levels in ArcMap to style roads so that I have a banded feel. My problem is that at intersections and sharp turns, the cartography gives a broken effect in the road. How can this be resolved. I have tweaked and searched without success.

.

[image: Pic] Unwanted effect pointers in blue.

UPDATE EDIT:

After further investigation I had an effect closer to what I wanted but with some side effect. From left to right; First image shows (i)the settings in ArcMap (Symbol Property Editor) , (ii) Resulting effect solving the 'craked effect' but undesirable capping at the end and (iii) the desired effect at the end of a road.

.[image]

Comment: It is not possible to understand the quality of data that you have from the question. Is it a vertex or start/end of polyline in that points with style problems? Is it possible to post some of your raw data (at least several roads) in order to be able to recreate your problem?

Comment: These are vertices. Sample data for this portion: http://www.adrive.com/public/GYWzaq/SampleData_Symbol_Level.zip